# Kill child process without killing parent

Tags: python, windows

I am using os.system() to run a python program and am trying to log its output to the file. This works fine.

```
os.system("myprogram.py -arg1 -arg2 > outputfile.txt")
#something here to kill/cleanup whatever is left from os.system()
#read outputfile1.txt- this output file got all the data I needed from os.system()
```

The problem is that myprogram.py calls another python program which gives me the output i need but doesn't finish- I can even see the prompt become different as in the picture below

[image]

Is there a way to kill the child process when I get to the next line of my program 
I tried using os.system("quit()") and subprocess.popen("quit()", shell=False) and that didn't do anything.

I can't really use exit() because that just kills python all together.

Btw this stalls

```
f=subprocess.Popen("myprogram.py -arg1 > outputfile.txt") and then 
f.communicate() #this just stalls because the child program does not end.
```

Answer (score 1):

The program that is being called by `myprogram.py` lands you in the python prompt. Why that happens we cannot tell you unless you show us the code.

Using the `subprocess` module (which is more versatile) is preferred to using `os.system`.

But you're not using subprocess correctly. Try it like this:

```
with open('outputfile.txt', 'w+') as outf:
    rc = subprocess.call(['python', 'myprogram.py', '-arg1'], stdout=outf)
```

The `with` statement will close the file once `subprocess.call` is done. The program and its arguments should be given as a list of strings. Redirection is achieved by using the `std...` arguments.

After `myprogram.py` finishes, `rc` contains its return code.

If you want to capture the output of the program, use `subprocess.check_output()` instead.

Comment: I am left with the same problem though. The python prompt comes up and even rc.kill() or rc.terminate() don't do anything.

Comment: Is it possible for me to send quit() to the child left behind by the subprocess (the python prompt?)

Comment: If the child leaves behind a python prompt, there is something wrong with it. Try and _fix_ that instead of working around it.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. will do. Did find a temporary work around by doing -subprocess.Popen("taskkill /F /T /PID %i"%rc.pid, shell=True)